# how to remove folder from url using apache mod rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-routing

This is my current *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?load=$1 [PT,L]
```

And this is the URL:

```
http://domain.com/web-design/article/my-first-article
```

I need to remove "article" from URL.

Comment: Rewrite rules wont matter here since you already have a very generic rule. Your application routing will.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your .htaccess under public_html:

> `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
>
>    #Turn mod_rewrite on
>
>   RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /
>
>   RewriteRule ^((?!article/).*)$ article/$1 [NC,L]`

Then you can access your website as http://domain.com/web-design/my-first-article

Comment: thanks for quick answer but i need to keep my htaccess and just add rule to rewrite "article/". When i merge your code into my htaccess i got 500 internal server error.

Maybe i realy need to update my application router class?